# Try vs try - catch block

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala. I'm studying try-catch block from one of the websites, where I came to know that Scala also provides Try. Both Try and try-catch block performs the work of catching an Exception. Now my question is Scala already had a try-catch block which performed well then why scala introduced Try? What are advantages and use cases of Try over try-catch in Scala?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of both `try {} catch {}`,  `Try` monad is error handling but `Try` is a functional way of error handling with the functional composition available.

**Let's say you are writing an API to divide two numbers**, which will explode in the middle of running an application when bad data is provided with unexpected results being propagated to clients.

```
scala> def divisionWithoutErrorHandling(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x / y
divisionWithoutErrorHandling: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> val result = divisionWithoutErrorHandling(1, 0)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
  at .divisionWithoutErrorHandling(<console>:12)
  ... 28 elided
```

**`try catch ...` is a forced way to handle errors (java way). And if you forget to catch errors (because compiler does not tell you at compile time), you are doomed.**

```
scala> @throws(classOf[Exception]) def divisionWithErrorHandling(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x / y 
divisionWithErrorHandling: (x: Int, y: Int)Int

scala> val result = divisionWithErrorHandling(1, 0) // compiler does not tell you about you need to handle errors here.
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
  at .divisionWithErrorHandling(<console>:11)
  ... 28 elided

scala> val result = try { divisionWithErrorHandling(1, 0) } catch {case e: Exception => 0 }
result: Int = 0
```

**Now, `Try` adds a functional way of handling an operation by encapsulating the operation.** Since `Try[T]` is a return type there is you get a reminder that you need to handle it gracefully in case of failures.

`Try[T]` has two results Either `Success` or `Failure`. When the operation fails, the return type will be of type `Failure` otherwise `Success[T]`.

```
scala> def divisionWithFnErrorHandling(x: Int, y: Int): Try[Int] = Try { x/y }
divisionWithFnErrorHandling: (x: Int, y: Int)scala.util.Try[Int]

scala> val result = divisionWithFnErrorHandling(1, 0)
result: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
```

And also you can chain the operations with `Try`,

```
scala> divisionWithFnErrorHandling(100, 2).map(x => x * 100).map(x => x + 200)
res5: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(5200)
```

So, `Try[T]` tells clients that the return type is `Try[T]` so its clients responsibility how they want to handle errors.

You can also use `Either[Throwable, T]` for error handling but it depends how you write an API.